# (JavaScript & HTML) Change opacity of button on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I was creating a button that when clicked, would change the opacity to 0.5.  If clicked again, it would go back to normal.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I tried:

```js
$(() => {
  $(document).on("click", ".test", function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('test').style.opacity = "0.5";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="test"></button>
```

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail about what it is or isn't doing that you are wanting/expecting?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` return array, change to `document.getElementsByClassName()[0]` to get the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a class system. JQuery has a `toggleClass` function which I would use for the job.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".test").toggleClass("transparent");
});
```

and CSS would be

```
<style>
    .test {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .test.transparent {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="test">Button</button>    

<script>
$(".test").on( "click", function() {
    $(".test").css("opacity", 1.5 - $(".test").css("opacity"));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try This**

```
<button class="button_click">CLICK HERE</button>

<style>
 .button_click{background:#F00; color:#FFF; padding:10px 50px; border:none; cursor:pointer;}
 .transperent{opacity:0.5;}
</style>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        $(".button_click").toggleClass("transperent");
     });
  });
</script>
```

**NOTICE:**
Please include this file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Jsfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshm/f3m6g24w/13/

Answer (score -1):

jQuery also provides a `toggleClass` function as it say, toggle the class:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".test").toggleClass("toogleTransparentClass");
});
```